# Android NDK C++ files keep file structure

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate a c++ library I've created for iOS into an android project that uses the NDK to build .cpp files.  My problem is that in iOS, I can include files using :

```
#include "MyFile.h"
```

Which works just fine, regardless of where these files are placed, provided that I link it to my Xcode project.

However, if I place the files using their normal file structure, including a .h that is not in the same file requires a relative url.  Something along the lines of :

```
#include "../MyOtherFolder/MyOtherFile.h".
```

Is there a way to mimic the Xcode behaviour (flat file hierarchie) using Android Studio?  Perhaps there is a setting / flag to be specified in the build.gradle file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly add other include directories to be considered by Android Studio using cFlags/cppFlags.

For example:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "mymodule"
    //...
    cppFlags  += "-I${file("src/main/jni/MyOtherFolder")}".toString()
    //...
}
```

Comment: This works well for single folders but does not follow the folder structure inside of it.  Are you aware of a way to recursively add other folders?  Something like "src/main/jni/MyOtherFolder/**" so that I don't have to add /subFolder1, /subFolder2, etc manually.  Isn't the worst if I have to but would same some time.